# How to make object property optional based on other type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I think the best way to explain my scenario is with code:

```js
interface IPluginSpec {
  name: string;
  state?: any;
}

interface IPluginOpts<PluginSpec extends IPluginSpec> {
  name: PluginSpec['name'];
  // How to require opts.initialState ONLY when PluginSpec['state'] is defined?
  initialState: PluginSpec['state'];
}

function createPlugin<PluginSpec extends IPluginSpec>(
  opts: IPluginOpts<PluginSpec>,
) {
  console.log('create plugin', opts);
}

interface IPluginOne {
  name: 'pluginOne';
  // Ideally state would be omitted here, but I can also live with having to
  // define "state: undefined" in plugins without state
  // state: undefined;
}

// Error: Property 'initialState' is missing in type...
createPlugin<IPluginOne>({
  name: 'pluginOne',
  // How to make initialState NOT required?
  // initialState: undefined,
  // How to make any non-undefined initialState invalid?
  // initialState: 'anything works here',
});

interface IPluginTwo {
  name: 'pluginTwo';
  state: number;
}

createPlugin<IPluginTwo>({
  name: 'pluginTwo',
  initialState: 0,
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with a conditional type. With it you can test for the existence of the property and either have or not have the extra property :

```
interface IPluginSpec {
  name: string;
  state?: any;
}

type IPluginOpts<PluginSpec extends IPluginSpec> = PluginSpec extends Record<'state', infer State> ? {
  name: PluginSpec['name'];
  initialState: State;
} : {
  name: PluginSpec['name']
}

function createPlugin<PluginSpec extends IPluginSpec>(
  opts: IPluginOpts<PluginSpec>,
) {
  console.log('create plugin', opts);
}

interface IPluginOne {
  name: 'pluginOne';
}

// Ok
createPlugin<IPluginOne>({
  name: 'pluginOne',
  // nothing to add
});

interface IPluginTwo {
  name: 'pluginTwo';
  state: number;
}

createPlugin<IPluginTwo>({
  name: 'pluginTwo',
  initialState: 0,
});
```

For a more composable approach you can use an intersection, with a common part, and each optional part in it's own conditional:

```
interface IPluginSpec {
    name: string;
    state?: any;
    config?: any;
}

type IPluginOpts<PluginSpec extends IPluginSpec> = {
        name: PluginSpec['name']
    }
    & (PluginSpec extends Record<'state', infer State> ? { initialState: State; } : {})
    & (PluginSpec extends Record<'config', infer Config> ? { initialConfig: Config; } : {})
```

The conditional type is very useful for callers. The problem is that inside the implementation, typescript can't really reason about the conditional types (since `T` is not known).

The best solution is to keep a public signature (with conditional types) and a simplified implementation signature (without conditional types). This will let you implement the function without type assertions while giving the caller the desired behavior:

```
function createPlugin<PluginSpec extends IPluginSpec>(opts: IPluginOpts<PluginSpec>)
function createPlugin<PluginSpec extends IPluginSpec>(opts: {
    name: string
    initalState: PluginSpec['state'],
    initialConfig: PluginSpec['config'],
}) {
    if (opts.initalState) {
        opts
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great! Do you think it would be possible to apply this technique to more than one optional attribute? Eg. if `IPluginSpec` and both optional `state` and `config` and `IPluginOpts` could receive `initialState` and `defaultConfig` respectively.

Comment: @treznik added a version that should work if you have multiple optional properties based on different condtions

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot. I'll keep this open until I get the chance to try it out.

Comment: Works well, thank you. One last question if you don't mind. How do I safely check if a plugin has state in the `createPlugin` method? For example, `if (opts.initialState)` will throw a type error, which is a bit unexpected to me because I thought TS will narrow down the type this way.

Comment: @treznik edited the answer to address this question.

Comment: Cool. I got "Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation." initially, but it seems to work once I make the optional properties optional in the private signature (eg. `initialState?: PluginSpec['state']`). It makes sense, right?