# How to make react props optional and required based on other props in react with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, web-frontend

I have a react button container component which returns a regular button or a icon button or a icon only button based on the type provided by the user using the prop. The following is the `ButtonContainer` component with the relevant type definitions for the `Props`

```
type ButtonWrapperProp = {
    label?:string;
    icon?:React.ReactNode;
    onClick:()=>void;
    type:'text'|'icon'|'iconOnly';

}

export const ButtonContainer = (props: ButtonWrapperProps) => {
    const {
        type = 'text',
        onClick,
        icon = <></>,
        label = '',
    } = props;

    const rendorButton = () => {
        switch (type) {
            case 'text':
                return (
                    <Button onClick={onClick}>{label}  <Button/>
                );

            case 'iconOnly':
                return (
                     <IconButton onClick={onClick}>
                       {icon}
                     </IconButton>
                );

            case 'icon':
                return (
                     <Button startIcon={icon}>
                       {label}
                     </Button>
                );

            default:
                return (
                    <Button onClick={onClick}>{label}  <Button/>
                );
        }
    };
    return <>{rendorButton()}</>;
};
```

The following is how I use the ButtonContainer component

```
<ButtonContainer type="iconOnly" onClick={onClick} icon={<DeleteIcon />}/>
<ButtonContainer type="text" onClick={onClick} label='Text button'/>
<ButtonContainer type="icon" onClick={onClick} label='Text and icon button' icon={<DeleteIcon />}/>
```

In the above code, the icon prop is optional because that is only used by icon button and regular buttons with icons. What I want is to only make the `icon` prop optional if the type passed from the `ButtonConatiner` is `text` and if the type passed to `ButtonCOntainer` is `icon` or `iconOnly` it should be a required prop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make object property optional based on other type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54416282/283366)

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).

The type prop works as a discriminator, allowing you to narrow ButtonWrapperProps to union members.

Also note that I could make the properties on each union member required, giving me good experience on usage site - after setting the type, TS is smart enough to hint which additional props are required.

```ts
type TextButtonProps = {
  type:'text'
  label:string;
  onClick:()=>void;
}

type IconOnlyButtonProps = {
  type:'iconOnly'
  icon:React.ReactNode;
  onClick:()=>void;
}

type IconButtonProps = {
  type:'icon'
  icon:React.ReactNode;
  label:string;
  onClick:()=>void;
}

type ButtonWrapperProps = TextButtonProps | IconOnlyButtonProps | IconButtonProps;

export const ButtonContainer = (props: ButtonWrapperProps) => {
  const renderButton = () => {
      switch (props.type) {
          case 'text':
              return (
                  <Button onClick={props.onClick}>{props.label}  </Button>
              );

          case 'iconOnly':
              return (
                   <IconButton onClick={props.onClick}>
                     {props.icon}
                   </IconButton>
              );

          case 'icon':
              return (
                   <Button startIcon={props.icon}>
                     {props.label}
                   </Button>
              );
      }
  };
  return <>{renderButton()}</>;
};
```